# In-app subscription Upgrade/downgrade in IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, apple-developer

I am new to IOS in-app purchases. Implemented in-app subscriptions in our app. Everything is working fine. Now we have to upgrade and downgrade the subscription. Created a subscription group in the apple developer account and created 6 different subscriptions.

Searched different docs related to in-app purchases. When the user wants to upgrade the subscription, we need to notify the user about the upgrade details and refund. There is no pop-up reflecting. How to notify the user about this? Like below

[image]

I see somewhere if the upgrade/downgrade is successful, we can see it in the receipt validation response. I am not seeing it in my response. It taking as a normal subscription payment.

What are the rules we have to follow for upgrade/downgrade subscriptions before proceeding? Any guidance helps me a lot.

EDIT: I noticed that receipt validation json response after paying for a higher subscription in the subscription group. "pending_renewal_info" is presented. Does that mean the subscription upgrade is happening? Every time I am paying for another subscription it shows me a normal payment pop-up, not like the first screenshot.

[image]

Comment: You don't need to do anything except process renewal transactions correctly. If the user upgrades the you will see a new transaction for a subscription at the higher tier. Process this as you would any subscription purchase. Apple will take care of the financials and also inform the user what is happening. For a downgrade, the user continues on their existing level until the end of the current subscription period. They will then renew at the lower level. Again, simply process this as you would any renewal.

Comment: Users can even upgrade/downgrade subscriptions in their apple account settings rather than in your app. This is why apple takes care of everything.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Paulw11 I attached an image. I am talking about this. We implemented our own payments in our app.

Comment: You don't do anything on your side like Paulw11 said. Apple handles all of the communication with the customer you just tread it like any other purchase. Apple does not want you communicating with the customer about anything payments related really.

Comment: @Lakshmi I don't quite understand what you are asking; you can see from your screenshot, Apple shows the dialog, or is this an example not from your app?  You say "we implemented our own payments in our app"; you can't do this. Your app will be rejected. You must use Apple's IAP

Comment: @Paulw11 This is an example screenshot from another website, not from my app. That is what I want to implement in my app. I am using Apple's IAP.

Comment: Then you don't need to do anything. Put your subscription IAPs in a subscription group and provide the UI that allows people to purchase them. Apple handles the upgrade/ downgrade for you.